# Using Google TrafficLayer API?

Tags: iphone, google-maps, traffic

Anyone have an idea of how to use Google's TrafficLayer API?

Looks like it's Javascript only. Any idea how to use/convert output to Array for use with MKMapView? Haven't really used it.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html

(do find on the page for trafficlayer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a few months without an answer, so I'm suspect the question isn't so clear. I accept the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed JavaScript only.

Here's an example of how to use the traffic layer http://jsfiddle.net/herostwist/ZLY43/1/

If you enable the console log line (and use firebug, chrome's console or the like) you can inspect the trafficlayer object and try to extract what you need from it.